# Does Googlebot trigger onclick events and index the resulting content?

Tags: seo, google, javascript, googlebot

I've found many topics about Googlebot following links and executing ajax queries but none that tell me whether onclick events would get triggered and results crawled.

Let's say that an image is loaded when another element on the page is clicked:

```
 <img src="#" data-src="path/to/image.jpg">
 <span onclick=" this.previousElementSibling.src = this.previousElementSibling.dataset.src; ">click</span>
```

I would like to know if this image would get crawled by Googlebot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, SEO recommendations have centered around having ‘plain text’ content whenever possible. Dynamically generated content, AJAX, and JavaScript links have been a detriment to SEO for the major search engines. Clearly, that is no longer the case for Google. Javascript links work in a similar manner to plain HTML links (at face value, we do not know what’s happening behind the scenes in the algorithms).

You can see whole testing **[here.](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)**

Comment: It's also worth doing a fetch and render in Search Console. If text is visible - Googlebot can definitely see it. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en

Comment: Google now expects all your javascript and CSS to be accessible. If it renders, it's relevant.